# ¿Cómo cargar un elemento como seleccionado con Select2?

Tags: javascript, ajax, select2

Mi problema es que al cargar los datos, intento que el primer elemento aparezca como `selected="selected"`, apareciendo así encima del `input` de mi web y mi programa crea ese atributo en la etiqueta, pero el *plugin* `select2` no es capaz de ver ningún evento y por eso no lo representa.

De este modo solo cuando selecciono un segundo elemento desde la web, me aparece el seleccionado y que había generado de forma dinámica mediante *AJAX*.

He visto algunos casos similares pero no consigo arreglarlo.

```
function loadDeviceElements(tag, sN){
    var cont = 0;
    $("#SensorsActuatorsList").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        async: true,
        url:getContextPath()+"/user_area/getConnectedElementAndActuatorList",
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {"serialNumber": sN},
        success: function(response){

            list = document.getElementById("SensorsActuatorsList");
            sensors = document.createElement("optgroup"); 

            sensors.setAttribute("label", "Sensors");
            list.appendChild(sensors);
            list.appendChild(actuators);

            for(key in response.elements)
            {
                //response.elements[key].id;
                sensorsOption = document.createElement("option");
                sensorsText = document.createTextNode(response.elements[key].tag);
                sensorsOption.setAttribute("value", response.elements[key].tag);
                sensorsOption.appendChild(sensorsText);
                sensors.appendChild(sensorsOption);
                if(cont === 0){
                    sensorsOption.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
                    cont++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

<select multiple style="width:100%" class="select2" id="SensorsActuatorsList"
</select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: select2 no hace lo que quiero]

Comment: quieres que te aparezca como seleccionado o quieres que lo añada también entre los tags? Qué aparece en este momento? El primer elemento o un recuadro en blanco? En tu código no se ve en dónde invocas el constructor de select2 sobre tu elemento select.

Comment: Quería que apareciese dentro del input I/O Filters, de modo que siempre que se cargaran los datos apareciera el primero y no estuviese el input vacío... @Fernando Forcén como muy bien me ha respondido bastaba con añadir  $("#SensorsActuatorsList").val(response.elements[key].tag).trigger("change"); y con esto invocamos el evento para que aparezca. Un saludo.

Comment: @JoséAntonioM LLegastes a resolver tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que sería más fácil si después de hacer la carga marcas el elemento seleccionado. Podrías hacer algo como `$("#SensorsActuatorsList").val("{valor del elemento que quieres seleccionar}");`